# Level Button not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, game-engine, android-launcher

I made a game in android studio, the user has to collect as many stars as possible before getting hit by the obstacles. I have 3 levels in this game but I want to manually be able to pick the level in the "Game Over" screen. I have a restart button in the "Game Over" screen that I use for the level 1 button because it does the same thing but I cant figure out how to manually pick level 2 or even level 3. The error I got is

`" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"`. Any help in what I need to add (or take out) would be greatly appreciated.

Game Engine class:

```
  if(theLevel >= 2){
                newLevel = 2;

                canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().images[tubes.get(i).getNumber()], tubes.get(i).getTubeX(), tubes.get(i).getTopTubeY(), null);

            }
```

Game Over class:

```
  private Button  level2btn;

level2btn = findViewById(R.id.level2btn);

public void level2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GameOver.this, GameEngine.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        AppConstants.gameEngine = new GameEngine();
        GameEngine.newLevel = 2;
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

XML:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/level2btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="224dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="224dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:onClick="level2"
        android:background="@drawable/level2btn" />
```

Comment: When this is executed:
level2btn = findViewById(R.id.level2btn);
What's the value of level2btn? I suppose it should be null if it's in the same class as the level2(View view) right?

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov Yes it should be null.